# Implement autosave on input tag in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to implement the Google Tasks Add Task feature (See pic for reference). Basically, when you click on Add Task button, it opens an input field which autosaves as you type. I'm trying to implement this in React.js.

[image: Google Tasks]

```js
class App extends Component {

  state = {
    showInput: false,
    addTaskInput: ''
  }

  showAddTask = (e) => {
    this.setState({showInput: true})
  }

  saveInput = (e) => {
    this.setState({addTaskInput: e.target.value})
  }

  render() {
    const {showInput, addTaskInput} = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <Button
          message="Add Task"
          bsStyle="primary"
          onClick={this.showAddTask}
        />
        { showInput && <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Add Task here..."
          value={addTaskInput}
          onChange={this.saveInput}
        /> }
        <TodoList addItem={}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my code. `App` is my main component. `TodoList` is the component which has the whole list of Todos. What I am going to do is:
*When I type something in the input, it fires `onChange` and sets the state. Inside onChange I would also change the `addItem` prop which would re-render `TaskList`*. This doesn't seem very optimal because of unnecessary re-renders. I'm thinking of changing `addItem` prop when *focus on input is removed*.

How do I go about doing the latter? Alternative approaches are welcome.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html .... go through this link, your approach seems to be fine. The re-renders you are thinking about isn't a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say it depends on how much your app is doing; if it's just a simple app saving `onChange` is not bad, but if a lot else is going on, yeah you should optimise.

- onBlur
- mix keystroke and debounce (my favorite)
- when input is more than a set length

Comment: Yeah let me make it more question oriented.